# Multiply by zero operation in MIPS

Tags: mips

What happens in the receiving register if I do the following operation

`sw $t3,0(t2)`  ? where t3 and t2 are two already known registers.

Does the value of t2 register get evoked during the operation or does the compiler just uses the default answer to any multiplication by zero which is (0)?

Thanks!

Comment: This represents addition, not multiplication.  In some architectures/assemblers this might be written `[$t2+0]`, or `($t2+0)`, or `[R1, #4]`.  The brackets are historically evocative of dereference of pointer to memory.  That form `disp(reg)` also quite common.  See [base + offset and variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Base_plus_offset,_and_variations).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the '$' before 't2'. For sw and other similar instructions, the number outside of the parenthesis is the offset. For example if the base address of an array is stored in $t2, the value in $t3 will be stored at the 0 offset of that address (the 0 index of the array). Since MIPS is based off of 32-bits, each index in the array that you want to access can be multiplied by 4 to get the correct offset.